# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 php while saving json data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to read json data and insert it into mysql,
But all the columns seems to match with the values.

Where am i wrong in the below query:

**gmrjson.json:**

```
{
  "rtVisitInfoOpObjV1":{
  "version":"1",
  "visitorId":"vis1",
  "dwellTime":"0",
  "poiId":"poi1",
  "srId":"sr1",
  "zoneId":"zone1",
  "poiProximityConfidence":"0",
  "zoneProximityConfidence":"0",
  "poiPresenceConfidence":"15",
  "zonePresenceConfidence":"0",
  "normalizedTime":"1489574975000"
 }
}
```

**sample.php:**

```
<?php
//First: read data
$fo=fopen("gmrjson.json","r");
$fr=fread($fo,filesize("gmrjson.json"));
$array=json_decode($fr,true);
//Second: create $values
$rows = array();
foreach ($array['rtVisitInfoOpObjV1'] as $key => $value)
$rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";
$values = implode(",", $rows); //echo '<pre>';print_r($values);die;


//Save to DB
$hostname = 'localhost';                 
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

try 
{
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=nodejs", $username, $password);
   echo 'Connected to database<br />';
   echo "INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximi‌​tyConfidence,zonePro‌​ximityConfidence,poi‌​PresenceConfidence,z‌​onePresenceConfidenc‌​e,normalizedTime) VALUES " . $values;
   $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES " . $values) or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true)); 
    echo $count; die;
   $dbh = null;
   echo 'Success<br />';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Below is the description of mysql table

[image]

**UPDATE- Debugging generated query:**

```
Array
(
[rtVisitInfoOpObjV1] => Array
    (
        [version] => 1
        [visitorId] => vis1
        [dwellTime] => 0
        [poiId] => poi1
        [srId] => sr1
        [zoneId] => zone1
        [poiProximityConfidence] => 0
        [zoneProximityConfidence] => 0
        [poiPresenceConfidence] => 15
        [zonePresenceConfidence] => 0
        [normalizedTime] => 1489574975000
    )

)
Connected to database
INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximi‌​tyConfidence,zonePro‌​ximityConfidence,poi‌​PresenceConfidence,z‌​onePresenceConfidenc‌​e,normalizedTime) VALUES ('version', '1'),('visitorId', 'vis1'),('dwellTime', '0'),('poiId', 'poi1'),('srId', 'sr1'),('zoneId', 'zone1'),('poiProximityConfidence', '0'),('zoneProximityConfidence', '0'),('poiPresenceConfidence', '15'),('zonePresenceConfidence', '0'),('normalizedTime', '1489574975000')Array
(
[0] => 21S01
[1] => 1136
[2] => Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
)
```

Comment: What is the generated SQL query? learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-Injection

Comment: Is this the query generated by your program?

Comment: No i manually wrote the query and where do i debug for the generated sql query

Comment: Add `echo ("INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES " . $values` before the `exec ... ` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see your SQL is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximi‌​tyConfidence,zonePro‌​ximityConfidence,poi‌​PresenceConfidence,z‌​onePresenceConfidenc‌​e,normalizedTime) VALUES ('version', '1'),('visitorId', 'vis1'),('dwellTime', '0'),('poiId', 'poi1'),('srId', 'sr1'),('zoneId', 'zone1'),('poiProximityConfidence', '0'),('zoneProximityConfidence', '0'),('poiPresenceConfidence', '15'),('zonePresenceConfidence', '0'),('normalizedTime', '1489574975000') ...
```

it must be:

```
INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximi‌​tyConfidence,zonePro‌​ximityConfidence,poi‌​PresenceConfidence,z‌​onePresenceConfidenc‌​e,normalizedTime) VALUES (1, 'vis1', '0','poi1','sr1' ...)
```

And you should remove the single quotes arround the numeric values

Comment: This is the answer you were supposed to accept as it gives u extra info on other mistakes u did

Answer (score 0):

Your query is actually giving a pair of values instead of single values

instead of doing this:

`foreach ($array['rtVisitInfoOpObjV1'] as $key => $value)
$rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";
$values = implode(",", $rows); //echo '<pre>';print_r($values);die;`

do this

`foreach ($array['rtVisitInfoOpObjV1'] as $key => $value)
array_push($rows, $value);
$values = implode(",", $rows); //echo '<pre>';print_r($values);die;`